# += on a vector without boost

Tags: c++, boost, stl, vector, operator-overloading

Is there any way to use the += operator with a vector without using boost or using a derivated class?

Eg.

```
somevector += 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7;
```

would actually be

```
somevector.push_back(1);
somevector.push_back(2);
somevector.push_back(3);
etc.
```

Comment: boost isn't magic, it's standard c++. you can always implement it the same way.

Comment: Actually, some low-level stuff in boost is quite non-standard.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With a little ugly operator overloading, this isn't too difficult to accomplish.  This solution could easily be made more generic, but it should serve as an adequate example.

```
#include <vector>
```

Your desired syntax uses two operators:  the `+=` operator and the `,` operator.  First, we need to create a wrapper class that allows us to apply the `,` operator to push an element onto the back of a vector:

```
template <typename T>
struct push_back_wrapper
{
    explicit push_back_wrapper(std::vector<T>& v) : v_(&v) { }

    push_back_wrapper& operator,(const T& x)
    {
        v_->push_back(x);
        return *this;
    }

    std::vector<T>* v_;
};
```

Then, in order to use this in conjunction with `+=` on a vector, we overload the `+=` operator for a vector.  We return a `push_back_wrapper` instance so that we can chain push backs with the comma operator:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
push_back_wrapper<T> operator+=(std::vector<T>& v, const U& x)
{
    v.push_back(x);
    return push_back_wrapper<T>(v);
}
```

Now we can write the code you have in your example:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    v += 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7;
}
```

The `v += 1` will call our `operator+=` overload, which will return an instance of the `push_back_wrapper`.  The comma operator is then applied for each of the subsequent elements in the "list."

Comment: Oh, so the comma was also an overload in boost? o.o

Comment: Yep, that's pretty much what boost is doing. It's a bit of an abuse of the `,` operator, since that's not what the comma operator normally does, but it's perfectly legal C++. The C++ syntax can be made to do very strange things: http://www.xs4all.nl/~weegen/eelis/analogliterals.xhtml

Comment: @Tyler:  Ha ha ha.  I **love** the analog literals.  Pure ingenuity.  As for this (ab)use of the comma operator, I don't think I would use this in production code.  However, I do use a set of `+` and `+=` overloads to append a single element, a vector of elements, or a range of elements onto the back of a vector.  I did enjoy writing this, though... :-P

Comment: Hmm, what exactly is U used for?

Comment: @kotarou3:  If we used `T` for both parameters, then instantiation of the template would fail if we tried to do `vector<int> v; v += 3.0;`, because the first argument of the `+=` is of type `vector<int>`, so `T` would have to be `int`, but the second argument is of type `double,` so `T` would have to be `double`.  It can't be both.  By using a second type parameter, we can allow implicit conversions to take place as we would expect them to.  It isn't a problem with the `,` overload because the `,` overload is not itself a function template, it's a member function of a class template.

Answer (score 5):

Not with syntax like that, no. But you could do something like this:

```
int tmparray[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};

somevector.insert(somevector.end(), 
                  tmparray, 
                  tmparray + (sizeof(tmparray) / sizeof(tmparray[0])));
```

Comment: I'll use this if I can't find a better soloution :) My syntax is what I found in a source file not made by me, uses boost and compilies fine on MSVC. But I'm using MinGW

Comment: Boost likes to do all sorts of weird magic with operator overloading that makes the C++ syntax do all sorts of stuff it was never meant to. That's not a bad thing, but don't expect to find the same kind of cleverness in the standard library.

Comment: I'm surprized that nobody saw these two bugs: `&tmparray` is a pointer to the array, not to the first element. What you should have written is `&tmparray[0]` instead. Secondly, `sizeof(tmparray)` is the size in *bytes*. You have to divide this by `sizeof(tmparray[0])`.