# How does boost's `list_of` converts to other collections?

Tags: c++, boost

Is a documentation describing how does boost's `list_of` [internally](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/boost/assign/list_of.hpp) converts to other collection?

Specifically, which role does `adapter_converter` and `converter` fill in the implicit conversion process.

Comment: short answer will be to take a peek at list_of.hpp (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/boost/assign/list_of.hpp).

Comment: I provided an example of how this is done in an answer to [`+=` on a vector without Boost](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428903/on-a-vector-without-boost)

Comment: @yasouser, I did that, but this is not so short, and not too easy to grasp (at least for me).

Comment: @Elazar-Leibovich: I spent quite a time to at least present a gist of what I understood and then wrote that one line because I felt I may not be giving the exact big picture. I too didn't fully understand how everything is stitched together, but have some vague idea.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find the document about the internals of `list_of`.
The below is very simplified version of `list_of`.
Probably the implementation detail will be different between distinct
versions, but I suppose basic process is roughly like the following.
The point of the question, the conversion to other collections is
implemented with templated conversion function.

**EDIT**:
IIRC adapter containers like `std::stack/queue` cannot be constructed/assigned
from a range.
So, `to_adapter` returns an `adapter_converter` instead of constructing the
destination container directly.
The templated conversion function in `adapter_converter` constructs the
adapter container with `push`.
As for class `converter`, in my understanding, it is a kind of mix-in.
It is used for hiding the details and provides abstraction in some degree.
However, I think it doesn't have much relevance to the point of the question
(conversion to several collections) directly.

```
template< class T >
struct generic_list {
  typedef std::deque< T > converter;
  converter values_;

  generic_list& operator()( T const& u ) {
    values_.push_back( u );
    return *this;
  }

  template< class Container >
  operator Container() const { // conversion function
    return Container( values_.begin(), values_.end() );
  }

  struct adapter_converter {
    converter const &gl;

    adapter_converter( converter const& gl ) : gl( gl ) {}

    template< class Adapter >
    operator Adapter() const { // conversion function for adapter
      Adapter a;
      converter::const_iterator i = gl.begin(), e = gl.end();
      for ( ;  i != e;  ++ i ) a.push( *i );
      return a;
    }
  };

  adapter_converter to_adapter() const {
    return adapter_converter( values_ );
  }
};

template< class T >
generic_list<T> list_of( T const& t ) {
  return generic_list<T>()( t );
}

int main() {
  std::stack< int > s = list_of(1)(2).to_adapter();
  std::queue< int > q = list_of(3)(4).to_adapter();
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I assumed this is something like that, but I didn't ask "How would you do list_of conversions", I asked "how does boost implements list_of conversions", specifically, which role does `adapter_converter` and `converter` fill.

Comment: Though I'm not 100% confident this fulfills all your requirements,
please see the edit.

Comment: Thanks! I still need to get a good look at it, and compare it to boost's source. I'll report here when I'm done.