# Can someone explain this C++ comma operator short-circuiting example?

Tags: c++, boolean, operators, short-circuiting, comma-operator

Can someone explain this C++ comma operator short-circuiting example?

```
bIsTRUE     = true, false, true;
bIsFALSE    = (true, false), true;
bIsAlsoTRUE = ((true, false), true);
```

Why does the second version short-circuit and return **false** (at least in MSVC++) and the other two versions do not but return **true**?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The comma operator has lower precedence than assignment, so these are parsed as

```
(bIsTRUE     = true), false, true;     
(bIsFALSE    = (true, false)), true;   
(bIsAlsoTRUE = ((true, false), true));
```

The comma operator does not short-circuit.  It evaluates its left operand, ignores the result, then evaluates its right operand.

`bIsTRUE` is `true` because the right operand of the assignment is `true`.

`bIsFALSE` is `false` because `(true, false)` evaluates `true`, ignores the result, then evaluates and yields `false`.

`bIsAlsoTRUE` is `true` because `((true, false), true)` evaluates `(true, false)`, ignores the result, then evaluates and yields `true`.

Comment: Ah, a case where the added parenthesis explain all!

Comment: Just out of curiosity where would you use such functionality?

Comment: @PeterR.: Which functionality, that comma is lower precedence than assignment? `int count = 0; for (Node *p = head; p; p = p->next, ++count) {}` A poor example, but for-loop increment expressions, and sometimes other similar things, can use it.

Comment: @Fred Yup that! I actually never noticed that I used that! Thanks :)

Comment: @Peter R.:  In addition, it's possible to overload the comma operator, which is [occasionally fun and useful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428903/on-a-vector-without-boost/3428925#3428925).

Comment: Can the comma operator be overloaded for intrinsic types like "bool" or "int"? Or can you only do it with classes.

Comment: @Adisak:  As with all operator overloading, at least one of the operand types must be a class or enumeration type.  So, you could overload the operator for `MyClass` and `int` (to be able to use `MyClass, 42`) but not `int` and `int` (`42, 42`).

Comment: Great... I knew there was some limitation where you couldn't do it with purely intrinsic types.  Thanks for clearing that up.